# PhoneGap Cordova Hammer.js HTML5/Javascript Canvas - "Tap" doesn't work properly

Tags: cordova, canvas, touch, hammer.js

I am trying to make an app using `phonegap/cordova/hammer.js` via `HTML5/Javascript/Canvas`:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
Hammer(c).on("tap", function(event){ /*Do something simple*/ });`
```

I am using the `<canvas id="myCanvas">` tag in my html.

Now for the problem: Tap only works once in a while (maybe once every 5-10 taps), and sometimes I find "hotspots" where it works multiple times in a row, but for some reason the "hotpot" randomly changes after a while. Whats going on?

Also I'm trying to use the "pinch" which can't get to work at all. Basically I want something as simple `"Zoom In" => count++; "Zoom Out" => count--;`

I'm a big amateur and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a `div` that lives above your canvas and attach the `tap` event there instead. I've had problems in the past with events directly on the canvas element.